# Hash added to model cannot be used as the field for the Select form tag helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, hash

I have added a hash to a model (populated from a many-many association) and would like to create selects in the view that can be used to alter the associations.  The only problem I have is in the view itself, where I would like to use a construct like:

```
<% categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= select :location, "group_hash[category.id]", category.enumerate_paths) %>
<% end %>
```

ROR chokes on the "group_hash[category.id]" with the error message:

```
undefined method `group_hash[category.id]' for #<Location:0x107fa2aa0>
```

even though it is defined.  when I build the construct manually with the following code:

```
<%= tag "select", {:id => "location_group_hash_#{category.id}",
                 :name => "location[group_hash[#{category.id}]]" }%>
<%= options_for_select category.enumerate_paths, 
                     @location.group_hash[category.id] %>
```

it works perfectly.  Am I doing something wrong in my attempt to use the select form tag helper, or is this just a limitation of the helper?

Comment: Have you tried <%= select :location, "group_hash[#{category.id}]", category.enumerate_paths) %> ?

Comment: @Gerry Sorry, I had a typo in my original post.  That is what I tried.  The bottom line is that it does not like [value] in the method name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to use the #select form helper to access the hash defined in your model. The #select form helper ultimately (if you follow it back) calls the #options_from_collection_for_select helper. That code is below.

As you can see, what you pass in as the "method" (second parm) to the #select form helper, becomes value_method in the second call, and ultimately gets called on the receiving object via a #send method call. So, what happens is ruby tries to do this:

```
@location.send("group_hash[category.id]")
```

...thus the undefined method error. I do not know of any way to pass in the additional parms you would need to pull the appropriate value from your hash when using the #select helper, though the #send method does allow additional parms to be sent in.

You might conceivably accomplish what you're after with some hackish method_missing override, but as you said, the other case using the options_for_select works. Rather than the separate #tag and #options_for_select calls, may I suggest you use a **#select_tag**, which expects the output from an #options_for_select in its second parm

```
  # File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb, line 339
def options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
  options = collection.map do |element|
    [element.send(text_method), element.send(value_method)]
  end
  selected, disabled = extract_selected_and_disabled(selected)
  select_deselect = {}
  select_deselect[:selected] = extract_values_from_collection(collection, value_method, selected)
  select_deselect[:disabled] = extract_values_from_collection(collection, value_method, disabled)

  options_for_select(options, select_deselect)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have a feeling I'm going about this in the wrong way, and that's why I'm having to kluge around the implementation.  My later question addresses that whole topic, but no responses so far.

Comment: Yes this is totally right. The select helper limits you in the way that you cannot pass the additional params you want in the send call. Even though I do not know why you have to write this, you have to go and implement your own select helper that does what you want (i.e. gives you the option of passing additional parameters to the send call)